# Java: reading in multiple lines of scanner

Tags: java

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
Scanner input8t = new Scanner("");
  if(countsystems(args[0]) == 1){
    while (input8.hasNextLine()) {
    String scanstring8 = "";
    scanstring8 = input8.nextLine();
     if(scanstring8.equals("")){
      break;
     }
    scanstringadd8 += "\n" + scanstring8;
    }
} else {
    while (input8.hasNextLine()) {
     String scanstring8 = "";
     scanstring8 = input8.nextLine();
      if(scanstring8.equals("")){
       break;
      }
     scanstringadd8 += "\n" + scanstring8;
    }
}
input8t = new Scanner(scanstringadd8);
```

The code must read in a 'system' like this:

```
(<E>,<A#>,A#),(A#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
( A#,<A#>,  ),(  ,B#,  ),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
(   ,    ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  ),(  ,  ,  )|
( Ab,<Ab>,  ),(  ,Bb,  ),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
```

The program works fine if there are more than one of such systems underneath each other. But it gives a NoSuchElementException later. Maybe it expects more lines? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Is this your entire code ?

Comment: No this code is contained in a for loop that is executed once if there is one 'system'. It is executed twice when there are two of them etc. I left that out.